# Only extract rows with Date Time overlaps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am working with a data frame shown below. Within there are 2 columns that I would like to find out true date and time overlap rows based on **values_1** column. The **values_1** column has multiple item that repeats and from that I would only like to extract rows where the start date_time and end date_time (both datetime) overlap for that specific value within values_1 column.

Below is data frame I have:

| values_1 | uniqId | DeptId | Start DateTime | End DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VGM | 1278 | BKNG | 2023-09-07 18:35:28 | 2023-09-07 20:05:28 |
| VGM | 1259 | BKNG | 2023-09-07 18:55:18 | 2023-09-07 19:25:38 |
| VGM | 2567 | BKNG | 2023-09-07 14:29:38 | 2023-09-07 17:35:28 |
| WEH | 9854 | ASKG | 2023-09-05 13:45:58 | 2023-09-05 15:00:00 |
| WEH | 9124 | ASKG | 2023-09-05 17:25:28 | 2023-09-05 19:43:13 |
| WEH | 9785 | ASKG | 2023-09-05 16:15:21 | 2023-09-05 18:24:02 |
| POH | 3479 | ASKG | 2023-09-06 15:35:29 | 2023-09-06 17:25:22 |
| POH | 3449 | ASKG | 2023-09-06 15:45:28 | 2023-09-06 18:35:19 |
| PNM | 4579 | FHDU | 2023-09-04 14:15:29 | 2023-09-04 18:25:22 |
| PNM | 4987 | FHDU | 2023-09-04 14:45:28 | 2023-09-06 18:35:19 |

And the output table I would like to achieve is:

| values_1 | uniqId | DeptId | Start DateTime | End DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VGM | 1278 | BKNG | 2023-09-07 18:35:28 | 2023-09-07 20:05:28 |
| VGM | 1259 | BKNG | 2023-09-07 18:55:18 | 2023-09-07 19:25:38 |
| WEH | 9124 | ASKG | 2023-09-05 17:25:28 | 2023-09-05 19:43:13 |
| WEH | 9785 | ASKG | 2023-09-05 16:15:21 | 2023-09-05 18:24:02 |
| POH | 3479 | ASKG | 2023-09-06 15:35:29 | 2023-09-06 17:25:22 |
| POH | 3449 | ASKG | 2023-09-06 15:45:28 | 2023-09-06 18:35:19 |
| PNM | 4579 | FHDU | 2023-09-04 14:15:29 | 2023-09-04 18:25:22 |
| PNM | 4987 | FHDU | 2023-09-04 14:45:28 | 2023-09-06 18:35:19 |

So from above output table, POH is completely removed because NO time overlaps. Along with VGM and WEH 2 rows are dropped because their times did not overlap with among **values_1** items. POH and PNM, both showed overlap and hence were part of the output.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

I would like to extract data with overlapping time periods that has non-consecutive order dates. I did not find any example that I can apply to my data frame.

Thanks!

Comment: By overlap, do you mean that the `end time -> start time` will be a subset of another row's `end time -> start time`  and grouped by the first column?

Comment: Hi Suraj, if I understand you correctly, yes, the start time and end time that has overlap in time for values_1 column should be grouped by. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
from itertools import combinations


def find_overlaps(g):
    idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(
        g["Start DateTime"], g["End DateTime"], closed="both"
    )

    to_keep = set()
    for (i1, interval1), (i2, interval2) in combinations(zip(g.index, idx.values), 2):
        if interval1.overlaps(interval2):
            to_keep.add(i1)
            to_keep.add(i2)

    return g.loc[list(to_keep)]


df["Start DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Start DateTime"])
df["End DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["End DateTime"])

out = df.groupby("values_1", group_keys=False).apply(find_overlaps)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  values_1  uniqId DeptId      Start DateTime        End DateTime
8      PNM    4579   FHDU 2023-09-04 14:15:29 2023-09-04 18:25:22
9      PNM    4987   FHDU 2023-09-04 14:45:28 2023-09-06 18:35:19
6      POH    3479   ASKG 2023-09-06 15:35:29 2023-09-06 17:25:22
7      POH    3449   ASKG 2023-09-06 15:45:28 2023-09-06 18:35:19
0      VGM    1278   BKNG 2023-09-07 18:35:28 2023-09-07 20:05:28
1      VGM    1259   BKNG 2023-09-07 18:55:18 2023-09-07 19:25:38
4      WEH    9124   ASKG 2023-09-05 17:25:28 2023-09-05 19:43:13
5      WEH    9785   ASKG 2023-09-05 16:15:21 2023-09-05 18:24:02
```

Comment: Hello @Andrej Kesely, this was a perfect solution. I really appreciate your time and support in providing this. Thanks!